# OctoberCMS using Ajax API with no-script fallback in page php section

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

My current base for a simple contact form is:

A page containing the form and the form validation in the php section with a native function like so:

```
function onStart(){if(Request::isMethod('post')) /* do stuff */}
```

Above is my "no-script" solution.

Now, when I want to enable OctoberCMS' Javascript API I have to call a self defined function in the php section, for example:

```
function onSubmit(){/* do stuff */}
```

How could I combine both in one function so that `/* do stuff */` triggers, regardless if the request was send via Ajax or pure php?

Comment: Good that you answered this. I believe you can add your own answer to this question instead of just editing your original post. So that people know it has been answered.

Comment: Thank you, will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

OctoberCMS provides a native method to let a form trigger a custom `onMyfunction()`, just by using another way of implementing the form.

For anybody who might get into the same problem, here's the code:

```
<?php
function onMyfunction(){}
?>
==
<html>
{{ form_open({ request: 'onMyfunction', id: 'my-form' }) }}
</html>
```

This will send the post data to the php handler, regardless if Javascript is enabled or not.
Now you only need to initiate your Ajax API with:

```
<script>
$('#my-form').submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).request('onMyfunction',{})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the html `<noscript>` tag?? In your css you would put `.noscript {display:none;} .script {display:block;}` then in your pages, component template, layout etc you could have two forms that change depending on if the user is using script or not. They can use the same `onSubmit` function.

Any user interaction with any of the sites I have made assume some might not use Javascript so I default to use standard forms and not js or ajax.